# Python code to change all xlsx files in directory to CSV corrupting original file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am writing a python code to change all files in a directory to csv then fill in missing time stamps with a row with NaN values and save to a new file.  The code is working however it is corrupting my original file for some reason.

**Excel error when trying to open original file**

> "excel cannot open the
>   file because file format or extention is not valid.  Verify that the
>   file has not been corrupted and the extension matches the format of
>   the file"

Here is the code I am using

```
import os, re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

inputdirectory = input('Enter the directory: ')
directory = os.listdir(inputdirectory)
os.chdir(inputdirectory)

for file in directory:
    data_xls = pd.read_excel(file, 'Sheet2', index_col=None)
    data_xls.to_csv(file, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col="DateTime", parse_dates=True)
    df = df.resample('1min').mean()
    df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq="1min"))
    df.to_csv(os.path.basename(file) + "-processed.csv", index=True, index_label="DateTime", na_rep='NaN')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data_xls = pd.read_excel(file, 'Sheet2', index_col=None)
data_xls.to_csv(file, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

means that you're dumping csv data using your xlsx filename.

Excel doesn't recognize it's csv because the extension is xlsx and the file appears as corrupt (and you actually lose data when doing that: renaming back to .csv allows to read the data, but you lose formatting, other sheets if any...). But pandas happily reads back your csv data even if it's called .xlsx, so you think your code works fine.

Solution: Use another name for that temporary file.

My humble non-expert fix:

```
import glob,os

inputdirectory = input('Enter the directory: ')

for xls_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(inputdirectory,"*.xls*")):
    data_xls = pd.read_excel(xls_file, 'Sheet2', index_col=None)
    csv_file = os.path.splitext(xls_file)[0]+".csv"
    data_xls.to_csv(csv_file, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

As a bonus, the script doesn't use `os.chdir` and processes only `xls` files. It uses the same radix name for .csv temp files, but doesn't overwrite the .xls files.

Aside: I'm not a pandas expert, but I'm sure this temporary file can be avoided somehow.

Comment: The csv file it is saving to is working, but when I try to open up the original xlsx data file it won't let me.

Comment: that's because pandas can read csv data from the corrupt xlsx file, as csv format like you specified.

Comment: thank you this worked perfectly.  What is the advantage to using glob as opposed to os.chdir?

Comment: first, `glob` filters the pattern, second, it provides absolute paths, so you don't have to chdir. Changing directories is not really good, because if you use relative paths, and you do it twice, it will fail the second time. Also, callers are unaware of this directory changing, and that breaks OO-programming / encapsulation.

Comment: beautiful -- thanks. much better than the other examples I found on SE